# Kiselev vs Euclid? High school Geometry

Tags: soft-question, euclidean-geometry, physics, book-recommendation

I wish to study High School Geometry from scratch. My goal is to be able to study College Level Physics, i.e. Mechanics, Optics, Electricity and Magnetism. I want some opinions on which book to use Kiselev's Geometry or Euclid's Elements with the supplementary text Geometry: Euclid and Beyond. Can you please give me some thoughts on the matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hartshorne's book *Geometry:Euclid and Beyond* isn't really intended to teach geometry from scratch. Instead, it's a detailed investigation of various issues related to the foundations of Euclidean geometry.

I wouldn't recommend reading the *Elements* directly. Later if you're interested in the foundations of geometry, you can read them along with Hartshorne's book.

Using Kiselev's book is an entirely reasonable choice, but you'll need to learn analytic geometry (with vectors) somewhere else later. In fact, you'll find that that's even more important for physics.

If you want to learn high school geometry in an easier book than Kiselev's, you could try *Basic Geometry* by Birkhoff and Beatley, although it doesn't discuss solid geometry. You could also consider *Geometry* by Lang and Murrow.

Comment: Would I be able to do well in College physics with only a knowledge of high school geometry with Birkhoff's Basic Geometry as text? Or should I continue with Kiselev?

Comment: Yes, I think you'd be okay with just one of the books, but regardless, you'll need to learn analytic geometry somewhere. The book by Lang and Murrow combines both.

Comment: I would not say that "Basic Geometry" by Birkhoff and Beatley is *easier*, it is just  *more boring*. (The authors are good guys, but they did not have enuf teaching experience.)

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid Euclid's Elements, opting instead for a more modern treatment. Also, based on your stated future goals, what you want is strong geometric computation and visualization skills, with only a minimal focus on things like straight-edge-and-compass constructions, or the axiomatic stuff.

Here are some texts that I would recommend:

Gibson -- Elementary Euclidean Geometry - An Undergraduate Introduction (2003)

Aarts -- Plane and Solid Geometry (2008)

Those books appear to assume some knowledge of Linear Algebra, so if you haven't had any of that, I would hold off on the above books.

I'll keep looking.

Update: After reflecting a little more, I can't find *any* Geometry text that fits well with your stated future goals.

Instead, I would review Precalculus and Calculus -- that material should be regarded as your base, and you should aim for *mastery* not just competence.

Then head towards Vector Analysis, Linear Algebra, and Differential Equations.

Along the way, you'll pick up the neeeded Geometry, without the parts that are extraneous to your goals.

Comment: And that modern treatment would be Kiselev's Geometry?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kiselev's Geometry. I'll edit my post to give a book I'd recommend.